# Using jQuery or just plain Javascript is it possible to change to a custom cursor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know it is possible to use jQuery to do something like:

```
$('body').css('cursor','wait');
```

What I want to know is: is it possible to change the cursor to a custom loading animation, such as a simple 'spinner' gif?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you do getting it working satisfactorily, I'd suggest using classes if possible rather than manipulating CSS directly, i.e., set up a class with your desired CSS and apply the class rather than changing the cursor directly.

Comment: OK. Why is that exactly? You mean do something like $('body').addClass('loading_cur');? Is this more efficient than changing the CSS directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just manipulating CSS on the fly here. See [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#cursor-props) — URIs are acceptable. Browser support is variable. I haven't tried it in years, but last time I did Internet Explorer required the cursors to be in .cur format.

That said, while it is possible, there are a good set of standard cursors that users **recognise**. It is rare that you will have thing usefully represented by a cursor that isn't covered by the standard list, and when that list does cover things it should be used so users don't have to learn a new icon.

Comment: The reason I want to do it is purely aesthetical. I don't think the user will have any problems recognizing what a spinning gif animation means, however I'm going to use something like :link,:visited { cursor: url(example.svg#linkcursor), url(hyper.cur), pointer }
so that even if the .cur isn't recognised it will still show that something is loading.

Answer (score 1):

yes, have a look at this page

[custom cursor](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-custom-cursor.html)

or this

[custom cursor - 2](http://www.swish-db.com/tutorials/view.php/tid/388)  (easier to understand/customize i guess)

(but using non-default cursors is probably not a great idea)